# Build fails due to postsharp error: Pipe server exited prematurely with exit code 1

Tags: c#, .net, postsharp

i am unable to build projects and solutions when postsharp is part of the project.
even when postharp is not used but only installed as nuget, the build fails.

when building, i get the following behaviour: 
build stalls and opens multiple postsharp-x64-srv.exe processes that use 100% of the cpu.
when i manually stop the processes, i get following errors:

- pipe server exited prematuraly with exit code 1.
- PostSharp.targets(333,5): warning : The server shut down while waiting for PipeAvailableEvent.

it appears that the proxy enviornment from work is the issue (see below for description)

### background

- i use visual studio 2017 on windows 10.
- i work behind a proxy that requires authentication
- postsharp version is 6.0.27

### already tried

- already set the host to native => no luck
- disabled the pipeserver => no luck
- already tried the latest version (6.0.33) and has the same result.

### what does work (but is not acceptable behaviour i think)

- building on home computer (so without the proxy environment from work)
- building with all networkadapters disabled on work computer

please advise on how this can be resolved

Comment: Do you get any different error messages when building with a native host? Do you have any antivirus software installed on your work computer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this issue was resolved after adding following path to my antivirus exceptions:

> C:\ProgramData\PostSharp